# Getting object from SelectionChangedEventArgs e Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, object, windows-phone-8, selectionchanged

I am using Telerik Slide View control and it supports a `SelectionChanged` event

```
private void radSlideView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{        
    var addedItems = e.AddedItems;
}
```

`e` contains the `MainViewModel` object which contains the `FileName` property. How do I "extract" the `FileName` property from `e`? `addedItems` is a`System.Collection.IList` type

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to cast:

```
if(e.AddedItems.Length > 0)       // make sure there is at least one item..
{
   MainViewModel firstItem = e.AddedItems[0] as MainViewModel;    // cast..
   if(firstItem != null)                                          // if not null..
   {
       string fileName = firstItem.FileName;                      // get the file name
   }
}
```

Comment: Is this the most proper way to resolve it? I'd expect some method to getting into a list without as'ing, casting or referencing the zero'th element. It seems just unsafe (although I see the protector again empty collection) and works only if we know the type to cast to (and it can't change or we'll have a poof)...

Comment: @Konrad, unfortunately WPF is full of trade-offs like that. It's a trade-off between flexibility and safety.